# Error while installing composer Syntax error in php.ini file

Tags: php

I want install composer. But when I am typing `install composer`, it is showing that PHP:

> syntax error, unexpected END_OF_LINE, expecting '=' in
>   C:\xamppNAV\php\php.ini on line 2

And I looked through the `php.ini` file, there is nothing on line 2

How can i solve this and install composer?

**PS. You can see my php.ini code in picture below:**

[image: php.ini]

Comment: Can you show your full php.ini, please?

Comment: I have added the picture of php.ini, as you see there nothing on line 2. Do you need full code in text format or is this picture enough ? @aynber

Comment: The code would be better, but I can see the issue from that image. See that `v` before `[PHP]` on the first line? Remove it.

Comment: Goodness, it should have been obvious to you v[php] on the first line.   Delete that 'v' character and save.

Comment: Thank you all, it is working))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `v` from line 1.

Line 1 should look like this:

```
[PHP]
```

You should remember to restart your server after such changes.

[Check here for reference](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/php.ini-production).